# Differential equation $y^{(4)}+y^{'''}=\cos(2x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve $y^{(4)}+y^{'''}=\cos(2x)$.

I started to solve normally such as finding $y_0$. $$y^{(4)}+y^{'''}=0$$
$$r^4+r^3=0\Rightarrow r=0, r=-1$$
$$y_0=c_1e^{-x} +c_2+c_3x+c_4x^2$$
But now, I don't know how to find $y_p$ because I don't know how take the particular solution. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is correct for $y_0$. For the particular solution, handle it by the Method of Undetermined Coefficients.

The particular solution to $y^{(4)} + y^{(3)} = \cos(2x)$ will be given as

$$y_p(x) = a_1\cos(2x) + a_2\sin(2x)$$

where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are constants.

Compute now the following derivatives :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^3y_p(x)}{\mathrm{d}x^3} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\mathrm{d}^4y_p(x)}{\mathrm{d}x^4}$$

Now, plug them into the equation $y_p(x)^{(4)} + y_p(x)^{(3)} = \cos(2x)$ and compute $a_1, a_2$.

The final solution, as you noted, is : $$y(x) = y_0(x) + y_p(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

Three integrations can be applied directly to lead to a first order differential equation as seen by:
\begin{align}
y'''' + y''' &= \cos(2 x) \\
y''' + y'' &= \frac{1}{2} \, \sin(2 x) + c_{0} \\
y'' + y' &= - \frac{1}{4} \, \cos(2 x) + c_{0} x + c_{1} \\
y' + y &= - \frac{1}{8} \, \sin(2 x) + \frac{c_{0} x^2}{2} + c_{1} x + c_{2}.
\end{align}
Now using the integration factor $e^{x}$ it is determined that
\begin{align}
e^{-x} \, \frac{d}{dx} ( e^{x} \, y) &= - \frac{1}{8} \, \sin(2 x) + \frac{c_{0} x^2}{2} + c_{1} x + c_{2} \\
y(x) &= e^{-x} \, \int_{x} e^{t} \, \left(- \frac{1}{8} \, \sin(2 t) + \frac{c_{0} t^2}{2} + c_{1} t + c_{2} \right) \, dt \\
&= - \frac{1}{40} \, (\sin(2 x) - 2 \, \cos(2 x)) + \frac{c_{0} x^2}{2} + (c_{1} - c_{0}) \, x + (c_{2} - c_{1} + c_{0}) + c_{3} \, e^{-x}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let's let
$$
z(x) = y'''(x).
$$
Then your ODE becomes a first-order linear ODE:
$$
z' + z = \cos(2x)
$$
and can be solved using an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

Once you find $z(x)$, you can then examine the possibilities of what $y(x)$ can be.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(x) = y^{'''}$ so that
$$u' + u = \cos 2x$$

A solution to that is conjectured to be of the form $A\cos 2x + B \sin 2x$.  WIthout resorting to integration factors, we can just write out the differential equation
$$
(-2A \sin 2x +2B \cos 2x) + (A\cos 2x + B \sin 2x = \cos 2x \implies \\
(B-2A) \sin 2x + (2B+A) \cos 2x = \cos 2x \implies \\
B-2A = 0 \wedge 2B+A = 1 
$$
so a particular solution is 
$$
y''' = \frac15 \cos 2x + \frac25 \sin 2x \implies
y = y_0  - \frac1{40}\sin 2x + \frac1{20}\cos 2x
$$